# How to close a TimeEdit Picker dialog programmatically in Delphi on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am new to programming and am trying to build an app that selects a time via a native TimeEdit. Now if the user does not pick a time within a certain time the Picker window is supposed to close itself.

I use a Maguay MX android device.

What I have tried and thought to be the correct procedures:
TimeEdit.ClosePicker (worked on Windows but not on Android).
PickerService.CloseAllPickers (also worked on Windows but not on Android).

I hope you guys can help me out.

Edit:
There are no visible error messages, also not in the Logcat.

The waiting time goes by a Timer. As soon as the Picker is opened TimeEdit.OpenPicker (works), the Timer waits x seconds and then calls TimeEdit.ClosePicker.

Example Code:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Timer.Enabled = False then
    Timer.Enabled:= True;
  TimeEdit.OpenPicker;
end;


procedure TForm4.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer.Enabled:= False;
  TimeEdit.ClosePicker;
  if TimeEdit.IsPickerOpened = False then
    ShowMessage('Closed')
  else ShowMessage('Open');
end;
```

When on Windows, this code closes the Picker Dialog and displays the message Closed.
When on Android, the Picker Dialog stays open with this code and also displays the message Closed.

Comment: How did it `not work`, was there an error message? And show how you implement the wait

Comment: There are no error messages.

The waiting time goes by a Timer. As soon as the Picker is opened TimeEdit.OpenPicker (works), the Timer waits x seconds and then calls TimeEdit.ClosePicker.

Sadly I do not have another device to check if it's maybe because of the Maguay MX.